# Can I get into Denmark after my study visa has expired and use the 90 day rule?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas, copenhagen

I have a bit of a complicated situation. I have completed a semester abroad in Copenhagen from Australia over this past semester and am doing some post semester travel. **My visa/residence permit expires on the 14th of February** but for some reasons to do with a concert I'm planning to **extend my stay to the 21st** in London.
As the UK is not the Schengen area I am able to do the last stint of my travels there.
However, most of my luggage is left behind as I am backpacking and my flight is planned to take off in Copenhagen and changing the flight to leave from London is very expensive due to complexities the flight company. Am I able to enter Copenhagen for a day to get my luggage on the logic that I am just there using the Schengen 90/180-day rule, and not on my study visa?

Comment: Beyond the duplicate question's answers, it's likely that entering a country with a scheduled flight days afterwards will be a convincing reason to let you in. If I were you, I'd print the flight confirmation before entering Denmark again.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are an Australian citizen, or a national of another country with visa-free privileges in the Schengen Area, or otherwise have a visa valid for Schengen, you may enter within the short-stay rules.

Your days spent under a residence permit in the issuing country (theoretically; practically there are few ways to check) do not count against your short-stay limits; you should be prepared to demonstrate this using your expired residence permit or another official confirmation of your residence. Although Australian citizens do not usually face much scrutiny at the border at entry, exit immigration checks are relatively common to ensure you have not overstayed; but this should be straightforward, especially if you are exiting through Denmark (the country that issued your residence permit).